# Table of content working on mobile but not desktop

Tags: javascript, tableofcontents

Some context: This is a table of content for a blog, but i want the TOC in desktop and mobile to be in a different part of the site. So they both have 2 different scripts of their own. The problem now is i manage to get the mobile version of it to work, but the desktop doesn't seem to be working. Anyone know why? Maybe a clash of codes?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqrma.png)

```html
<!-- TOC -->
<script>
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const id = entry.target.getAttribute("id");
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach((z) => {
        z.classList.remove("active")
      });
      document.querySelector(`a[href="#${id}"]`).classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll("h2,h3").forEach(function(heading, i) { // runs a function for all headings inside your rich text element
    observer.observe(heading);
  heading.setAttribute("id", "toc-" + i); // gives each heading a unique id
  const item = document.createElement("a"); // creates an <a> element called "item" for each heading
  item.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML; // gives each item the text of the corresponding heading
  ("h2,h3").split(",").forEach(function(x) { // runs a function for each item in your headings list
    if (heading.tagName.toLowerCase()==x) {
      item.classList.add("tocitem", "toc-" + x); // gives each item the correct class
    }
  });
  item.setAttribute("href", "#toc-" + i); // gives each item the correct anchor link
  document.querySelector("#toc").appendChild(item); // places each item inside the Table of Contents div
});
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll("h2,h3").forEach(function(heading, i) { // runs a function for all headings inside your rich text element
    observer.observe(heading);
  heading.setAttribute("id", "toc-mobile-" + i); // gives each heading a unique id
  const item = document.createElement("a"); // creates an <a> element called "item" for each heading
  item.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML; // gives each item the text of the corresponding heading
  ("h2,h3").split(",").forEach(function(x) { // runs a function for each item in your headings list
    if (heading.tagName.toLowerCase()==x) {
      item.classList.add("tocitem-mobile", "toc-mobile-" + x); // gives each item the correct class
    }
  });
  item.setAttribute("href", "#toc-mobile-" + i); // gives each item the correct anchor link
  document.querySelector("#toc-mobile").appendChild(item); // places each item inside the Table of Contents div
});
</script>
```